# Solving a SDE using Feynman-Kac

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Apologies for any mathematical abominations I'm about to perform!

I'm trying to solve the following SDE

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(t,x) + \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2x^2\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}(t,x) = 0$$

$$F(T,x) = x^2$$

Where the solution can be shown to be $f(t,x) = x^2e^{\sigma^2(T-t)}$ for $0\leq t\leq T$.

By FK Formula

$f(t,x) = E[X^2_T \mid x_t = x]$

$dx_t = \sigma x^2 dB_t$     (This is the line where I think I've made a mistake)

That is $x_t = x_0 + \sigma x^2 B_t$

$f(t,x) = E[X^2_T \mid x_t = x]$

$E[X_t + \sigma x^2(B_T - B_t)^2 \mid X_t = x]$

So I think my $dx_t$ line is incorrect, I'm not sure how the $x^2$ term changes the $dx_t$, do I include the $x^2$ term with $\sigma$ or am I misunderstanding the FK formula.

Any help/working towards the solution is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You clearly understand how to use $\LaTeX$ to mark up your mathematics. Why do you only use it on *some* of the mathematical material, and not *all* of it? Because it is a mixture of all sorts of styles, it is hard on the eye and irritating to read. It is recommended that this be corrected.

Comment: Sorry i'm not great at LaTeX but i'm not sure what I've done wrong? I've tried to apply it where possible and the only place (Where I feel) I've butchered it is with the solution and I've included a screenshot to show how it should look

Comment: For a start you have f(t,x) which is not in $\LaTeX$ and $x^2$ which *is* in $\LaTeX$. This is bewildering in its unwisdom. You do know you can just put dollar signs round an entire expression rather than just one term at a time, surely?

Comment: That is a PDE in $f(t,x)$ you are attempting to solve, not a SDE. The solution via Feynman-Kac is a conditional expectation of the solution to a SDE describing the Itô process. Note the distinction.

Comment: I've fixed up your MathJax for you. Please take a look at the changes so you can write more legible MathJax in the future.

Comment: Thank you for that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an overview/sketch that I hope you may flesh out.

To solve the PDE,
$$f_t + 0.5\sigma^2 x^2 f_{xx}=0,$$
with terminal condition $f(T, x) = x^2$, we appeal to the Feynman-Kac connection. (Please excuse my use of subscripts for partial derivatives out of laziness).

---

**Identifying the SDE**

The FK says that the solution $f$ is a conditional expectation of the TC applied to an Ito diffusion:
$$f(t,x)= \mathbb{E}(X_T^2 | X_t =x),$$

where $dX_t = \sigma X_t dB_t$ and $B = (B_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is a Brownian motion. How we identified the correct SDE depends on the coefficients appearing in the above PDE. To put it in general terms, if we wanted to solve

$$f_t + \frac12 \sigma(x)^2 f_{xx}=0,$$
and then our SDE would satisfy
$$dX_t = \sigma(X_t) dB_t.$$
The special case here being $\sigma(x)=\sigma x$ (where $\sigma$ on the RHS is just a constant).

---

**Computing the PDE solution**

Now we identify $X$ is a GBM with zero drift, so that
$$X_t = X_0 e^{-0.5 \sigma^2 t +\sigma B_t},$$
which we can also write on $[t, T]$ as
$$X_T = X_t e^{-0.5 \sigma^2 (T-t) +\sigma B_{(T-t)}}.$$
Hence squaring and taking the conditional expectation $\mathbb{E}(\cdot | X_t=x)$ yields
$$f(t, x) = \mathbb{E}( X_t^2 e^{-\sigma^2 (T-t)} e^{2\sigma B_{(T-t)}} | X_t = x)$$
$$=X_t^2 e^{-\sigma^2 (T-t)} \mathbb{E}( e^{2\sigma B_{(T-t)}} | X_t = x)$$
$$=x^2 e^{-\sigma^2 (T-t)} e^{2 \sigma^2 (T-t)}$$
$$=x^2 e^{\sigma^2 (T-t)},$$
since we are conditioning on $X_t=x$ we can pull out $X_t^2$ and the non-random constant $e^{-\sigma^2 (T-t)}$ and finally we used the fact that $\mathbb{E}(e^{2\sigma B_{(T-t)}})$ is just the MGF, $M_{B_{(T-t)}}(s)$, of a $\mathcal{N}(0, T-t)$ RV evaluated at $s=2\sigma$.

Please comment if something is not clear or erroneous.

Comment: Thank you for such an incredibly detailed response! Pretty much everything is clear I just have a couple of quick questions. if say the power of x was 3 or 4, would it still be $dX_t = \sigma(X_t))$ and secondly i'm guessing this is going to be an extremely basic question but what's the big giveaway that X is a GBM? allowing us to use that form for $X_t$

Comment: @StocCalculusHelpPlease The general form of the coefficient function corresponding to the second-derivative in the PDE is $\sigma(x)^2$ for some function $\sigma(\cdot)$ (at least for the time-homogeneous case). So, if the PDE had the term $\frac12 b(x)^k f_{xx}$ for some function $b$, we would identify the diffusion coefficient for the SDE as $\sigma(x)=\sqrt{b(x)^k}=b(x)^{k/2}$, hence $d X_t = b(X_t)^{k/2} dB_t$ (assuming the PDE had no drift terms, still). Next, any GBM $X_t$ solves $dX_t = a X_t dt +c X_t dB_t$ for some $(a,c)$. Here $(a,c)=(0,\sigma)$. To see, apply Ito's to $\log X_t$

Comment: @StocCalculusHelpPlease (also by applying Ito's to $\log X_t$ where $X_t$ solves the general SDE of a GBM we obtain that form $X_t=X_0 e^{(a-0.5c^2)t +c B_t}$.)

Comment: Thank you so much it makes a lot more sense now! :)

Comment: @NapD.Lover i was trying to collect enough rep to comment, but thanks a lot for this. your answer was incredible in breaking down the feynman-kac theorem. just a slight question: how is the expectation $\mathbb{E}(e^{2\sigma B_{(T-t)}})$ the MGF $M_{B_{(T-t)}}(s)$ ? i mean it's correct, i was just wondering if there is a way to spot that that particular expectation yields that MGF?

Comment: @coffee-raid Thank you. The expectation $\mathbb{E}(e^{2\sigma B_{(T-t)}})$ is in the form of a generic MGF: $\mathbb{E}(e^{s X})$ where $s=2\sigma$ and $X=B_{(T-t)}$. But we know the distribution of $B$ at any time by definition:  $B_{(T-t)}\sim \mathcal{N}(0, T-t)$. Thus, if you know the MGF of a Gaussian, you're done. If you do not, you can compute it for a standard normal $Z$ and use the equality, in distribution, $B_{(T-t)}=\sqrt{T-t}Z$ and properties of MGFs to find $M_{B_{(T-t)}}(s)$ from $M_Z(s)$. Then plug in $s=2\sigma$. Does that help to spot it?

Comment: @NapD.Lover oh right, this helps. thanks again!